# read.csv() warning: unable to read a csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I was trying to read a csv file in R and read.csv gives me a warning and consequently stops reading from there on. I think it's something related to an extra quote being there. How can I resolve this?

(csv file put on a public share below for access)

```
> scoresdf = read.csv('http://aftabubuntu.cloudapp.net/trainDataEnglish.csv')
Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  EOF within quoted string
```

Comment: I'd imagine the problem has to do with encoding? Are you on Windows? You can try explicitly specifying UTF-8 encoding (the default for Windows is usually Latin-1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same error on `read.csv`. I managed to get it working with the `rio` package:

```
library(rio)
dat <- import("http://aftabubuntu.cloudapp.net/trainDataEnglish.csv")
```

and the `readr` package:

```
library(readr)
dat <- read_csv("http://aftabubuntu.cloudapp.net/trainDataEnglish.csv")
```

and the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("http://aftabubuntu.cloudapp.net/trainDataEnglish.csv")
```

Comment: thank you. This worked fine.
What is the cause of the warning/behavior earlier?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
url <- 'http://aftabubuntu.cloudapp.net/trainDataEnglish.csv'
scoresdf = read.csv(url,quote="")
```

As you suspected, there is indeed an embedded quotation mark somewhere within your document.